# Integrating Google hangouts in Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites, google-hangouts

is it possible to embed a javascript (or any widget) in a Google Sites page? 
What I need is a simple button that opens a new hangout, for example with a predefined email address. 
Example, when a user clicks on that button, he is automatically put in a HO that calls my email address.

I know that google Sites has many html/javascript constraints and I would like to know if / how can it be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780838/including-javascript-to-google-sites

Answer (score 0):

I think he can help you.  You use only the hangout App .

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button?hl=en

you can add button Hangout too .

```
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/hangout/1/gplus-hangout-15x79-normal.png"
    alt="Start a Hangout"
    style="border:0;width:79px;height:15px;"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Hangout URL from the button once clicked. it creates a fresh Hangout every time, and keeps it's location to itself.

A better process would be to create a Hangout event far in the future and get the resulting Hangout URL. Write your Javascript to use AJAX to Ping a server that emails you that a person is going to the hangout, and then change the user's current page href to the Hangout URL.

Hope this helps.